# What does prendre un canon mean?

Tags: sens, traduction, expressions

Macron recently said:

"Les non-vaccinés, j’ai très envie de les emmerder. [...] Il faut leur dire : à partir du 15 janvier, vous ne pourrez plus aller au restau, prendre un canon, boire un café, aller au théâtre, aller au ciné..."

What does prendre un canon mean?

Comment: Please check in a dictionary and then explain what you do not understand or where you are stuck.

Comment: Hint: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/canon/2

Comment: @livresque I certainly did check in a French-English dictionary but it clearly wasn’t a good enough dictionary.

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you! That’s very helpful.

Comment: Merci au président ! Beaucoup commencent à en avoir assez. Et après tout ça on va vouloir récupérer les sommes que nous avons collectivement dépensées inutilement pour soigner des gens dont la maladie de l'esprit est autrement incurable.

Comment: Always use a monolingual dictionary first. "have a drink".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means something along the lines of "drink a glass (of wine)"

Comment: Thank you!  The moral is that I need to get a better dictionary it seems. Google translate also doesn’t understand the expression.

Comment: @graffe google translate is not a dictionary and not very good on the whole (as far as translators  go DeepL is much better). [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/canon#Nom_commun_3) can be very helpful at times!

Answer (score 2):

> (...) Vendredi, l'animateur nous explique les racines de l'expression "boire un canon", qui désigne à l'origine une unité pour mesurer le vin. L'expression s'installera durablement dans le langage populaire à partir du 19e siècle. Il arrive souvent d'entendre certains donner rendez-vous à des amis pour "boire un canon". Une expression dont le sens se rapproche beaucoup de "boire un coup". Mais saviez-vous que cette expression tire son origine du 16e siècle ? À cette période, c'était une véritable unité de mesure pour le vin qui correspondait à un seizième de pinte, soit 6 centilitres. Les verres à l’époque avaient cette exacte contenance. Aujourd’hui, ils ont une contenance plus proche de 9 ou 20 centilitres, selon chez qui vous êtes invité. Au 19e siècle, l’expression "boire un canon" s’impose : elle signifie boire un simple verre de vin, quand on disait "boire un canon soviétique", c’était du vin rouge, et quand on utilisait le verbe canonner… c’est qu’on enchainait les petits canons. Aujourd’hui, en Irlande, on dit "boire une jatte". Aux États-Unis, l'expression utilisée est "to knock one back", qui veut dire : "On s’en tape un." En France, on peut aussi dire "s’en jeter un derrière la cravate", qu’on en ai ou pas. Chez les Roumains, l'expression est : "Béa un ciocan", qui signifie "boire un marteau" (...)

Source : https://www.europe1.fr/culture/pourquoi-dit-on-boire-un-canon-quand-on-prend-un-verre-de-vin-4039133

Answer (score 1):

It means to grab a drink at a not-so-fancy bar (the counter, not the place), often a cheap beer on draft or a glass of table wine in what's called a "verre ballon", which is a small stemmed perfectly round shaped glass of wine.

"Prendre un canon" is a popular expression, stricto sensu. Though, as a french native, I can't say I hear it a lot!

Comment: Ce doit être une question de génération, personnellement, je l'entends et l'utilise couramment.

Comment: colloquial, not popular.

Comment: @Lambie thanks for correcting me, I used the word popular thinking of "populaire" in french.

Comment: @Toto c'est possible, ou peut-être est-ce une expression plus commune dans certaines régions?